# How to get a friends UID using just there name FQL

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get the user ID of a friend using just there name. Coming from a SQl background I figure it would just be something like  `[Select] [UID] [From] friend [Where] Name = "friends name".`

So my query is

```
$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
    . 'fql?q=SELECT+uid+FROM+friend+WHERE+name=Friends Name'
    . '&access_token=' . $access_token;
```

What's the error in my logic here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of [`friend` FQL table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend) you should use [`user` table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user) to retrieve the `uid` of your friend against his/her name. This is because the `friend` table just stores the relationship between two `user` and not detail about them.

So your query should be as following

```
SELECT uid 
FROM user
where name = "Name" and uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me())
```

And as the `name` field is not indexable we need to filter the users in `user` table using `uid2` from `friend` table.

**Edit**

Your query needs to be changed to following to work

```
$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?'
     . 'q=SELECT+uid+FROM+user+where+name+%3D+%27User+Name%27+'
         . 'and+uid+in+%28select+uid2+from+friend+where+uid1+%3D+me%28%29%29'
         . '&access_token=' . $access_token;
```

Comment: could you update your answer to match php syntax I'm having trouble getting the name= "Name" to work.

Comment: When I replace the User and Name with my friends first/last name the query returns nothing. Also is there somewhere in the api documentation I missed that you learned where all of the special characters equal. For example you have a %3D instead of a =.

Comment: I just `urlencoded` the query string. Also make sure you are using the user access token to access the result. Also, just to check, use this query on Graph Explorer with your app selected from the list of available apps